# Deadlock during custom autograd.Function operation

Tags: deep-learning, torch, autograd

`class ClusterMemory(nn.Module, ABC):
def **init**(self, num_features, num_samples, temp=0.05, momentum=0.2, use_hard=False):
super(ClusterMemory, self).**init**()
self.num_features = num_features
self.num_samples = num_samples

```
    self.momentum = momentum
    self.temp = temp
    self.use_hard = use_hard

    self.register_buffer('features', torch.zeros(num_samples, num_features))

def forward(self, inputs, targets):

    inputs = F.normalize(inputs, dim=1).cuda()

    # outputs = cm(inputs, targets, self.features, self.momentum)
    inputs = store(inputs, targets, self.features, self.momentum)
    outputs = inputs.mm(self.features.t())

    outputs /= self.temp

    loss = F.cross_entropy(outputs, targets)
    # loss = neighbor_entropy(self.features, outputs, targets)
    return loss
```

class Store(autograd.Function):

```
@staticmethod
def forward(ctx, inputs, targets, features, momentum):
    # ctx.features = features
    ctx.momentum = momentum
    ctx.save_for_backward(inputs, targets, features)
    # outputs = inputs.mm(ctx.features.t())
    outputs = inputs*1.
    return outputs

@staticmethod
def backward(ctx, grad_outputs):
    inputs, targets, features = ctx.saved_tensors
    grad_inputs = None
    if ctx.needs_input_grad[0]:
        # print(ctx.needs_input_grad)
        grad_inputs = grad_outputs*1.

    # print(1)
    # momentum update
    # momentum update
    for y in torch.unique(targets):
        features[y] = ctx.momentum * features[y] + (1. - ctx.momentum) * \
                          inputs[torch.where(targets == y)].mean(dim=0)
        features[y] /= features[y].norm()
    # print(2)
    return grad_inputs, None, None, None
```

def store(inputs, indexes, features, momentum=0.5):
return Store.apply(inputs, indexes, features, torch.Tensor([momentum]).to(inputs.device))
`
Tried modifying saved_tensors to (inputs), (inputs, targets), (inputs, targets, features) to no avail

I try to save a few tensors so that when backpropagating I can update self.features in my own way

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.